# Ruby: Format already formatted date string

Tags: ruby, date, time

I have a date string that comes back like this: `02-22-2011` I need to turn that into Feb 22, 2011... is there anyway to easily due this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I used Chronic (http://chronic.rubyforge.org/)

`Chronic.parse('02-22-2011').strftime("%b %d, %Y")`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of requiring a gem just for this, you can also use `Time.parse`.

Comment: But `Date.parse('02-22-2011')`end in an error. (`Date.parse('02-22-2011')` works fine.  -- at least on my German PC. Perhaps a matter of localization. With `Date.strptime` you don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Date.strptime. It's kind of a revert strftime.
Then you can use strftime to get the string version of the date.

```
require 'date'
p Date.strptime('02-22-2011', '%m-%d-%Y') #-> #<Date: 2011-02-22 (4911229/2,0,2299161)>
p Date.strptime('02-22-2011', '%m-%d-%Y').strftime("%b %d, %Y") #"Feb 22, 2011"
```